# Norms and traces example

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Example:

Let $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ be a quadratic extention of $F=\mathbb{Q}$ with square-free integer $d$.Then,

$g_{a+b\sqrt{d}}(X)=(X-a-b\sqrt{d})(X-a+b\sqrt{d})=X^2 -2aX+(a^2 -db^2),$

so,

$Tr_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})/\mathbb{Q}}(a+b\sqrt{d})=2a$, $N_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})/\mathbb{Q}}(a+b\sqrt{d})=a^2-db^2$.

In particular, an integer number $c$ is a sum of two squares iff $c\in N_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})/\mathbb{Q}}O_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})}$.
More generally, $c$ is of the form $a^2 -db^2$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ and square-free $d$ not congruent to $1 \mod 4$ iff $c\in N_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})/\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$.

Can someone give me an explanation of why an integer number $c$ is a sum of two squares iff $c\in N_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})/\mathbb{Q}}O_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})}$?

Answer (score 2):

What your norm computation shows is that, for $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, the image of the norm to $\mathbb{Q}$ is exactly $\{a^2-db^2\} = \{a^2+b^2\}$. So an integer $c$ is of the form $a^2+b^2$ if and only if it is in the image of the norm.