# Is this formula for the minimal polynomial of a quadratic integer correct?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Given $\{a, b\} \in \mathbb{Z}$ (or $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ as appropriate) and $d \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $\mu(d) \neq 0$, the minimal polynomial of $a + b \sqrt{d}$ is $$x^2 - 2ax + (a^2 - db^2),$$ right?

Essentially $x^2$ minus twice the trace times $x$, plus the norm. If I have not made a mistake somewhere.

I don't have any theorems or intuitions to back this up. Just playing around with Wolfram Alpha, tossing it various real and complex quadratic integers.

One of the similar questions, [Norms and traces example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1240184/norms-and-traces-example), seems to confirm what I have come up with, but it doesn't rule out the possibility that I have overlooked some subtlety, or worse, something that should be obvious to me even at my novice level.

Comment: Assuming $d$ is not a square so $a + b \sqrt{d}$ is irrational, it can't have a linear minimal polynomial; and it is easily seen to be a root of your quadratic polynomial.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** If $x = a + b \sqrt d$, then

$$\begin{align}
x^2 - 2ax + (a^2 - db^2) & = (a^2 + 2ab \sqrt d + db^2) - (2a^2 + 2ab \sqrt d) + (a^2 - db^2)  \\
 & = a^2 + a^2 + 2ab \sqrt d - 2ab \sqrt d + db^2 - db^2 - 2a^2  \\
 & = 2a^2 - 2a^2 \\
 & = 0. \\
\end{align}$$

Of course these calculations assume that $b \neq 0$.

Suppose that $x^2 - 2ax + (a^2 - db^2)$ is not the minimal polynomial. Then the polynomial $x + c$, with $c \in \mathbb Z$ is possible. But since we've asserted $b \neq 0$ and $d$ is squarefree, $x \not\in \mathbb Z$ and $x + c = (a + c) + b \sqrt d \neq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative hint:  to *derive* (rather than just verify) the minimal polynomial, let $x = a + b\sqrt{d}\,$, which implies $(x-a)^2=b^2 d\,$, which expands to $\,x^2 - 2ax + a^2 - db^2 = 0\,$. The latter is a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ satisfied by $\,x\,$, and it is the *minimal* polynomial since $a+b\sqrt{d}$ is irrational when $d$ is not a perfect square, thus cannot satisfy a $1^{st}$ degree polynomial.